# How to obtain a value in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, p5.js

In the p5 javascript library, there's a built-in function `{key}` which is the key you press. For example `text(${key},200,200)` would display whatever key your pressing on 200,200. If I were to push the `{key}` value into an array so the array has the key value you pressed, then `console.log()` the value from the array, you'd get: Object {key: "a}. If you were to put this into a text, say you press "A" then you push A into the array. Then you put that into text (Granted A is the only value in the array) `text(Array_Of_Text[0],Xposition,Yposition);` The text is simply "Object, Object" So I'd assume I'd have to find the value from the object, which I don't know how to do.

```
let Text = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
background(220);
text(Text[0],200,200);
console.log(Text[0])

}
function keyPressed()
{
  Text.push({key})
}
```

Comment: you can just do `Text[0].key`

Comment: @dave doing that will give you an error because before the first key is pressed, you're trying to read the 'key' property of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the curly brackets around `key`, you can just say `Text.push(key)`.

The built-in function is simply `key`, not `{key}`. When you put brackets around it, it becomes an object according to [ES6 syntax](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/es6/es6_objects.htm). So if `key === "a"`, writing `{key}` is the same as writing `{key: "a"}`:

```
let key = "a";
console.log({ key });
console.log({ key: "a" });
```

The above code will print "Object `{key: "a"}`" twice. You can't test this using `==` or `===` because [JavaScript doesn't work like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects).

The same goes for any other variable or data type: if `valu === 200`, then `{valu}` is the same as `{valu: 200}`:

```
let valu = 200;
console.log({ valu });
console.log({ valu: 200 });
//prints "Object {valu: 200}" twice
```

Comment: Thank you for the simple answer, could you please elaborate on why this works this way. (Sorry for the extremely late reply)

Answer (score 1):

You can just nest things in javascript. I think you can even refer to objects like: Text[0][0]. Since you can totally have a: let string = "hello"; console.log(string[0])
> "h"

```
if(Text[0].key !== undefined){
    console.log(Text[0].key)
}
```

(And this has already been answered, i think)